# How to get a RabbitMQ Worker to notify my Mobile Front End?

Tags: android, rabbitmq

I have a mobile application that sends a request to a REST service. The REST Service will persist the data and Create a Request in RabbitMQ.

Once my RabbitMQ Consumer starts to process the request in the queue, I want to somehow notify my mobile application that the request is being processed.

Please can you provide me with some ideas as to how I can notify my Mobile Application?

Maybe using something like SignalR?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have 2-way messaging enabled between your mobile app and the REST server, with something like SignalR. But you also need two way messaging between the REST server and the back-end process that handles the real work.

When the request comes in to the REST server, send the request across RabbitMQ to the back-end code. The REST server should also be set up as a consumer of a "status" queue for the work that is being done.

When a messages comes into the "status" queue, the REST server will update it's database with the current status of the work. It can then use SignalR or Socket.IO or PusherApp or whatever other websockets or push mechanism you want, and send that status update out to the mobile device.

Comment: Revisiting this thread in 2022 and hope it's not a problem. could you please offer some resource for implementing this proposition? I'm trying to have a backend composed of multiple workers capable of processing a request coming from a `route` in a controller, the thing Is I want to wait for a response from my workers and then send the response as http to my front, I cant find any resource or example of that being done and the complexity for me is with having the dynamic functionality of chaining workers, meaning a worker is a consumer and a publisher at the same time, thanks